# How to write an expression in SSRS for Gauge Pointer?

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I am trying to make a report using SQL server 2012 SSRS. What I am trying to show is if one of the cells in any of the columns ( MaxC, AvgC, MaxU) of my table report becomes red (based on the threshold condition applied to the values), the Gauge Pointer (above the table) stays on the red zone, if any cell in any column changes to yellow then the gauge stays in the yellow zone and if green then stays in the green zone.  How to do I write an expression for this problem. This is what I have done for the first record in a MaxC column (for a value 2472) that was yellow. I was able to show the gauge pointer stays on the yellow zone, but I am not sure how to apply the similar logic for all the records in all the columns that I am interested on. Thanks

```
=Switch(Fields!MaxC.Value > 4000, "Red", Fields!MaxC.Value < 2000, "Green"
, true , "Gold")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the above expression works for the first cell `MaxC` and by default you can get the others to work individually? If so you are now concerned with aggregating this over the whole tablix, i.e. the whole dataset?

If so, I suggest you use a `Max()` function on the dataset in question like so:

```
=Switch(Max(Fields!MaxC.Value, "DatasetA") > 4000, "Red", Max(Fields!MaxC.Value, "DatasetA") < 2000, "Green" , true , "Gold")
```

And if you wanted to incorporate all three thresholds into one and if different, as I think you might:

```
=Switch(Max(Fields!MaxC.Value, "DatasetA") > 4000 
    OR Max(Fields!AvgC.Value, "DatasetA") > 3000 
    OR Max(Fields!MaxU.Value, "DatasetA") > 2000 , "Red",
    Max(Fields!MaxC.Value, "DatasetA") < 2000 
    OR Max(Fields!AvgC.Value, "DatasetA") < 1000 
    OR Max(Fields!MaxU.Value, "DatasetA") < 500 , "Green",
    true , "Gold")
```

**or**

```
=Switch(Max(Fields!MaxC.Value, "DatasetA") > 4000 , "Red",
    Max(Fields!AvgC.Value, "DatasetA") > 3000 , "Red",
    Max(Fields!MaxU.Value, "DatasetA") > 2000 , "Red",
    Max(Fields!MaxC.Value, "DatasetA") < 2000 , "Green",
    Max(Fields!AvgC.Value, "DatasetA") < 1000 , "Green",
    Max(Fields!MaxU.Value, "DatasetA") < 500 , "Green",
    true , "Gold")
```

Comment: glh, I really appreciate your suggestion. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome. Please help other users by accepting this answer.

Comment: Hi Glh, Could you please suggest why the Gauge pointer did not work when I used this expression.=Switch(Max(Fields!MaxCreat.Value,"DatasetA")<=8 or Max(Fields!AvgCreat.Value,"DatasetA")<=8 or Max(Fields!MaxUpdate.Value,"DatasetA")<=8 or Max(Fields!AvgUpdate.Value,"DatasetA") <=8, "red", Max(Fields!MaxCreat.Value,"DatasetA")>=15 or Max(Fields!AvgCreat.Value,"DatasetA")>=15 or Max(Fields!MaxUpdate.Value,"DatasetA")>=15 or Max(Fields!AvgUpdate.Value,"DatasetA") >=15, "Green", true, "Gold")

Comment: I tried the alternate answer as well but the pointer always stays at 1000 even though I see two red coloured cells in the table. It stopped working after I changed the threshold as I posted. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Your new thresholds are all less than 1000 so you'll always get green. Should these be in the 000's?

Comment: ya, I would also like to include negative values as well. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Just remember the `switch` function stops at the first satisfied query i.e. if you wanted -ves to be "green" they need to be placed in front of the "red" queries... But you probably already know that :)